# network packet creation/parsing library?

Tags: c++, parsing, networking, packet, ethernet

I'm looking for a library that helps with network packet creation/parsing. Something as [Python dpkg library](http://code.google.com/p/dpkt/). I need to change IP addresses, to check ports and to analyze payload of TCP/UDP packets which I have as Ethernet frames.

I know this can be done manually, e.g. as is presented in [WinPcap docs](http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/group__wpcap__tut6.html) or [libpcap docs](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html). Are there any library for this?

C++ on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look to [libcrafter](http://code.google.com/p/libcrafter/). It's a library for creation and decoding of network packets very similar to Scapy. Not sure if it can work on Windows but you can try.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been a while this answer but you should try [libtins](http://libtins.github.io/). It is a really versatile, object-oriented and efficient library.

Disclaimer: I was one of the creators of the library and it is actively maintained by Matias Fontanini.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the plugins and API for for Wireshark.